# TLS error when using docker-machine driver digitalocean

Tags: docker, digital-ocean, docker-machine

Receiving this error message when running `eval $(docker-machine env digitalocean)`:

`Error checking TLS connection: Error checking and/or regenerating the certs: There was an error validating certificates for host "<IP ADRESS>:2376": dial tcp <IP ADRESS>:2376: i/o timeout
You can attempt to regenerate them using 'docker-machine regenerate-certs [name]'.
Be advised that this will trigger a Docker daemon restart which will stop running containers.`

Command creating Docker container on Digital Ocean.

`docker-machine create --driver digitalocean --digitalocean-access-token=<ACCESS TOKEN> digitalocean`

Replace `<IP ADRESS>` and `<ACCESS TOKEN>` with valid values :)

Been googling this, but can't find any solution. Will verify Docker versions later today, but if anyone knows what the issue can be, you are welcome to help me out.

Comment: What `docker-machine ls` says?

Answer (score 0):

It looks that It maybe something related to your network,

The docker-remote machine is created but you cannot connect to it via TCP protocol.

- Try to connect to it via ssh `docker-machine -D ssh docker-machine-name` to confirm the hypothesis.

If you can ssh it means it's a network problem.

Change the network you are connected to and try again.

PS: I has that problem when I was connected to university wireless but when I changed the network everything start working